# How do you assign labels in P4V (windows)?

Tags: version-control, perforce

We use Perforce for source control at work and I primarily use it through the P4V GUI.

Now, I want to assign Perforce 'labels' to some of the directories in the repository, and I can't find a way how to.

I tried looking online, but the only thing I found was a way to do it through the command line (http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/label.html).

Is there any way I can do it through the GUI (P4V)? I have not used the p4 command line before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click in the labels tab.  Select New Label...

You must name the label.  You can set the View to cover only a section of the depot(s), or leave it wide open.

This will only create an empty label, with no file revisions.

Next, in order to add files to the labels, (with your label selected) you will click Label Files... from the Actions menu.  From this dialog you can add files/folders and specify the revisions of them to label.